SVG circle, what is the radius percentage of?
I have the following code:


.container{
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
    resize: both;     /* Just to make it... */
    overflow: hidden; /* ...resizable for testing. */
    
}
<div class="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="black"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>



As I resize .container, I can easily see that:

cx is percentage of the width
cy is percentage of the height

But I cannot understand what r is percentage of. What is r percentage of?

MDN: SVG Attribute r "When the value is set as a percentage, it refers to the normalized diagonal of the current SVG viewport."

Many thanks. I did check the MDN docs for circle, but I didn't understand one could click on r to read more about it

As commented by Roko C. Buljan when using % units the relative value refers to the normalized diagonal length.
See the W3C SVG 2 specs (working draft) "8.9. Units"

For any other length value expressed as a percentage of the SVG
viewport, the percentage must be calculated as a percentage of the
normalized diagonal of the ‘viewBox’ applied to that viewport. If no
‘viewBox’ is specified, then the normalized diagonal of the SVG
viewport must be used. The normalized diagonal length must be
calculated with sqrt((width)**2 + (height)**2)/sqrt(2).

here's an example


let w = 100;
let h = 200;
let c = Math.sqrt(w ** 2 + h ** 2) / Math.sqrt(2)
let rAbsolute = c * 0.25

// get absolute radius via baseVal
let r = c1.r.baseVal.value
console.log(rAbsolute, r)
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="container">
  <svg width="100%" height="200px">
        <circle id="c1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="#ccc"></circle>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="39.52847075210474" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
    </svg>
</div>



You can also check your calculations using the baseVal property from the SVGAnimatedLength interface.
If you actually need the circle scale more predictably you may also add a square-shaped viewBox. In this case the preserveAspectRatio (in the example below the default "xMidYMid meet") attribute will affect the alignment and scaling.


.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#ccc"/>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="black" />
    </svg>
</div>



As you can see the radius of the circle stays at 25% relative to the 100x100 viewBox (so the circle stays 50% wide).

Many thanks! I did check the spec for  first, and they never mentioned anything about how the percentage radius should be calculated. IMO a bit bad that one has to read a totally different part of the spec to get that info without any reference to it. But no problem, since I have the help from you awesome guys here :D

The described logic for relative units is not specific to <circle> elements or the r attribute. You can use relative % units for rects, lines, gradients and other elements as well as in attributes like width, height, x etc - hence it's a separate chapter in the specs. But frankly, the spec docs are quite often not masterpieces of "infotainment" - the length chapter is surprisingly comprehensible and clear ;)

I'm posting in case others are looking for the same thing I was looking for.
I needed the radius to be expressed as percentage of the smallest of the width and the height of the SVG element. I don't know how well browsers support it, but using the new container functionality in CSS with the cqmin unit worked well for me (tested in Firefox and Chrome).


.container{
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    
    background-color: red;
    
    resize: both;     /* Just to make it... */
    overflow: hidden; /* ...resizable for testing. */
    
    container-type: size; /* Add this one. */
    
}
<div class="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25cqmin" fill="black"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>




This is helpful information, but does not answer the question. Instead of posting this here, consider creating a new self-answered question with a title along the lines of "How to set radius to a percentage of width or height—whichever is smaller?"

Quite often these relatively new "parent-or-viewport" related relative units (vmin, cqmin etc) applied to SVG still introduce a lot cross-browser issues. (safari/webkit is the main party pooper) While your example is most certainly simplified and doesn't cover your actual requirements I highly recommend  to test if you could achieve the desired layout with tweaked viewBox and preserveAspectRatio settings. Quite  likely you can achieve a more robust rendering relying on SVG 's inbuild scaling features that may even work  in ie11 – keep in mind: the  S in SVG is well deserved and ;)
